# How create own callback

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I can't create a callback, I create interface

```
interface OnClick {
fun click() 
}
```

added it to your fragment xml, and called the method

```
        <variable
        name="onClick"
        type="com.android.todolist.OnClick" />
```

...

```
        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/floating_action_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/light_yellow"
        android:onClick="@{()->onClick.click()}"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/light_yellow"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_add_24"
        app:tint="@android:color/white"
        android:contentDescription="create item" />
```

and override method in my fragment

```
    override fun click() {
    Log.d("test","123")
}
```

but it doesn't work, how can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass the interface to the layout just pass the view ( fragment or activity) to the layout and call the function.

```
<variable
    name="view"
    type="YourFragment" />
```

and

```
    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/floating_action_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/light_yellow"
    android:onClick="@{()-> view.click()}"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/light_yellow"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_add_24"
    app:tint="@android:color/white"
    android:contentDescription="create item" />
```

It's work fine!